# Can I place a link to a package file (.m) in my Applications folder

Tags: packages, development

I am developing a package and would like to be able to test it without having to copy the package file to my `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` folder for each change, so it would be convenient for me to just create a Finder link or symlink pointing back to my working file. So far I have not been able to convince Mathematica to treat the link as a package file.  Am I missing a subtle technique that may make this possible?

Comment: For development purposes, I would just add the location of your file's directory to `$Path` via `AppendTo[$Path, directory-with-your-file]` - I think that's simpler.

Comment: Wolfram Workbench might be handy too

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the addition, that I have several machines (home, work, laptop) where I develop. What I wanted to have was a `GetDev` which works like the usual `Get` with the difference that it looks in my development folder for the package when it cannot not be loaded.

Therefore, I'm using the following function `GetDev` when I want to load my package which is in active development. It consists of two definitions. The first one extracts the dev-folder for the appropriate machine

```
GetDev::unknMach = 
  "The computer `1` is not known as development machine.";
GetDev[package_String] := 
  Switch[$MachineName, 
        "myMachineName", 
        GetDev[package, FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "workspace"}]], 
        _, 
        Message[GetDev::unknMach, $MachineName]
];
```

Here you can define dev-folders for each machine you have. Then `GetDev` is called again but with the path to the dev-folder. First it tries to load the package with the normal `Get`. We suppress the `Get::noopen` message but use `Check` to test for it. When the call to `Get` fails, we append the dev-folder to our `$Path` and try again.

```
GetDev[package_String, devpath_String] := 
  Module[{}, 
   Quiet[Check[
     Get[package], 
     (AppendTo[$Path, FileNameJoin[{devpath, 
             StringReplace[package, "`" -> $PathnameSeparator]}]];
      Check[
        Get[package],
        Message[General::noopen, package],
        {Get::noopen}
      ]),{Get::noopen}], 
   {Get::noopen}]
];
```

Some important details:

I'm using the usual *Wolfram Workbench* application structure. So if I develop a package `Blub` then the code for it is located in `mypath/workspace/Blub/Blub`. Important are the two nested `Blub` folders. This is why I'm not simply appending my development folder but instead, I use the package name as folder in this line:

```
AppendTo[$Path, FileNameJoin[{devpath, StringReplace[package, "`" -> $PathnameSeparator]}]
```

If you are using only one development machine, then you can define the dev-folder to be fixed. Btw, this is only a hacked version. If I would have to write it again, I would add some details like removing the added path, when the package could not be loaded.